# split("\\") and error

Tags: java

```
String str = "\u0054\u0068\u0069\u006e\u006b\u0050\u0061\u0064";

String[] strArray = str.split("\\");
```

but this error occured.

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1

Answer (score 28, accepted):

it should be

```
String[] strArray = str.split("\\\\");
```

the reason why is because in `Regex`, `\` has special meaning so you need to escape it into `\\`.

and in java, `\\` should be equal to `"\\\\"`

Comment: There is no slash in the original string.

Comment: @assylias yes there is no slash in the original string. But the exception being pointed out is because of invalid regex.

Comment: @MukulGoel I agree but it seems to me that the OP does not understand what the original string represents. It is up to each user to either answer the question being asked or to try to address a more fundamental problem: splitting a string on a character not present in that string makes no sense. I think the latter is more helpful.

Comment: @assylias if the problem is not on the regex why does it throws `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException`? the regex does not split the string if it there has no matches on the pattern right? not by throwing an exception. when you pass \ on regex appliction. it will surely prompt you for `Erroneous characters`

Comment: @JohnWoo Of course the exception is due to the invalid regex - what I'm saying is that splitting that string on slashes makes no sense: it does not contain any slashes.

Comment: @assylias yes it makes no sense but answering `makes no sense` does not make any sense at all. why not just explaining the OP why an error has been thrown?

Comment: @assylias , yup I somewhat agree with you, but not totally. what you doing is PROBABLY answering the next question that OP will face once he get past the current error. Also this could be a trick question about explaining usage of unicode characters, to demonstrate that the `strArray` will return `ThinkPad` how ? or to demonstrate the use of escape character `\u` , So instead of answering each assumed question, we should stick to the question.. Your info is useful though..

Comment: @assylias I agree with Mukul. I have learned from you today about unicode but sadly it does not answers the question. in your answer, you are using 4 backslashes but you did not bother to explain why did you use 4 backslashes instead of 2 backslashes.

Comment: @JohnWoo Fair enough - the reason I did not mention it is because it was already covered by other answers. But I get your point.

Comment: @assylias , #peace brother, you are right , its upto each user to address the question in their own way. (y)

Answer (score 4):

`String.split(String regex)` method take as parameter a `RegEx`.

RegEX for `\` is `\\\\`

Try

```
String[] strArray = str.split("\\\\");
```

Reason why we use `"\\\\"` ,

Regex for `\` is `\\`

Now `\\` is treated as `\` apply the escape character logic  ( `\n` = new line , `\\` = `\`)

So to have `"\\"` we use `"\\\\"`

Hope its not confusing.. :D

Answer (score 1):

That does not make much sense. Your original string uses unicode characters and is equal to `ThinkPad`. So there is no slash to remove anyway.

In other words, the code below prints `ThinkPad` twice:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "\u0054\u0068\u0069\u006e\u006b\u0050\u0061\u0064";
    System.out.println(str);
    String[] strArray = str.split("\\\\");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
}
```

Or even clearer, the code below prints true:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "\u0054\u0068\u0069\u006e\u006b\u0050\u0061\u0064";
    String str2 = "ThinkPad";
    System.out.println(str == str2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the general solution about escaping: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

```
String str = "\u0054\u0068\u0069\u006e\u006b\u0050\u0061\u0064";
String[] strArray = str.split(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava("\\"));
```