# Error: Unexpected internal error near index 1 \

Tags: java

I know this question has been asked here: [split("\\") and error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13175129/15746432), but I tried the answer provided and still have the same error:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1 \"
```

My main class is

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringUtil su = new StringUtil();
    String file_path = "C:\\Users\\com\\example\\Car.class";
    System.out.println(getFileName(file_path))
    System.out.println(getFileExtension(file_path));
}
```

Two things I've tried:

1.

```java
public static String getFileName(String str){
    String[] dirs = str.split("\\\\");
    String file = dirs[-1];
    String[] comp = file.split(".");
    return comp[0];
}
```

2. 

```java
public static String getFileName(String str){
    String str = str.replace("\\\\", " ");
    String[] dirs = str.split(" ");
    String file = dirs[-1];
    String[] comp = file.split(".");
    return comp[0];
}
```

Comment: That code will not throw that exception. (Currently it will throw a syntax error.) Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you not use other helper classes like `java.io.File`? It has methods like `getName()` you might want to use (depending on what you are trying to do).

Comment: `dirs[-1]` looks suspicious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few problems here:

1. `dirs[-1]` does not work in Java, use `dirs[dirs.length - 1]`
2. `"."` is a regex for any character
3. Most importantly, this method of working with paths is very error-prone, incomplete and with your current examples only works on systems with `\` as the separator. Use Java's [`Paths`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html) (or `File`) API.

It could look something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path path = Paths.get("com", "example", "Car.class");
    String withoutExtension = removeExtension(path.getFileName().toString());
}

public static String removeExtension(String filename) {
    int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i > 0) {
        return filename.substring(i + 1);
    } else {
        return filename;
    }
}
```